# Size of directory from os.Stat/Lstat

Tags: go, operating-system

Let's say I do an `os.Stat()` on a directory:

```
func main() {
    fi, _ := os.Stat("/tmp")
    println(fi.Size())
}

// 548
// Program exited.
```

https://play.golang.org/p/NIzGMHRYfi

What exactly is the `[FileInfo].Size()` value meant to represent? It's not the file size, so I'm guessing something like number of files? Inodes? I couldn't find a clear answer anywhere, so maybe someone can enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileInfo mentions

```
// length in bytes for regular files; system-dependent for others
```

So it really depends on the execution environment.
See for instance "[Where does ext4 store directory sizes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124983/7490)"

In that example, a directory stat size returns 4096 bytes.
That's the actual size of the directory itself, not what it contains.

> The stat command provides no facility for querying anything other then the size of a filesystem object (directory or file).
>
> `stat` simply doesn't have a way to return multiple sizes—so it can only return the size of the directory itself, not of its contents.
> And also "directory size including contents" becomes less clear when you have hardlinked files.

Comment: Thanks, nice link. On OSX again, all the sizes are different. Seems a bit silly to return a non-zero number here, but hey, I guess that size value might be of use to someone.